# React -Jest Invoke UseEffect

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jestjs

I have dependent useeffect in a code which changes states -

```
 useEffect(()=>{
     if(open)
      {
        setOpen(false);
      }    
    },[open]); //open is a state variable which changes with setOpen(true/false);
```

My code coverage is showing red lines for this. How can I test this with jest? (I am not allowed to use enzym due to some project reasons and decision is not into my hands)

I tried -

```
beforeAll(()=>{
    useState.mockImplementation(callback=>{
       return callback({
            open:true
         })
    }) 
});

test("Check State",async ()=>{
  render(<ControlToRender/>);
  await act(()=> expect(open).toBe(false);
})
```

I am getting error , when I do - npm run test -

```
useState.mockImplementation is not a function
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should test the component as balckbox, not the useState internal implementation itself. Something like - user action - expected behavior (element is visible or not). The approach of mocking globally useState is not sustainable. What if another developer adds another useState in the component?

More behavior driven example:

```
test("Given XXX the alert should be visible",async ()=>{
  render(<ControlToRender/>);
  await act(()=> {
    const errorMessageNode = screen.getByRole("alert");
    expect(errorMessageNode).toBeVisible();
  });
})
```

Comment: How can I trigger a state change?

Comment: Look at it from a user behavior perspective. What user action triggers what. The consumer of the Component and the end user does not know anything about states and effects. Example: If user clicks button a and if component.prop.isAdminUser equals to false - show an error panel. This can be tested. The question is what user action triggers your useEffect/ useState